# Solving the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s - e^{-s}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve de differential equation
$$ y'(t) = y(t-1) H(t-1) $$
where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function, but I got stuck solving an Inverse Laplace Transform:
$$ \mathcal{L}\{y'(t)\} = \mathcal{L}\{y(t-1)H(t-1)\} \\
sY(s)-y(0) = e^{-s}Y(s) \\
s - \frac{y(0)}{Y(s)} = e^{-s} \\
\frac{y(0)}{Y(s)} = s - e^{-s} \\
\frac{Y(s)}{y(0)} = \frac{1}{s - e^{-s}} \\
\frac{\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}}{y(0)} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{1}{s - e^{-s}} \right\} \\
\frac{y(s)}{y(0)} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{1}{s - e^{-s}} \right\}
$$
Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: It is not so simple as you are solving a [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). For the inverse transform, you need all the poles of $1/(s-e^{-s})$, this corresponds to ALL the branches of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $W_k(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the backward transform, you need all the zeros of $s-e^{-s}$. These are given by the $k$-th branch of the Lambert W function $W_k(1)$. The function is thus given by
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{1}{s-e^{-s}} \right\} = \sum_k \mathop{\rm Res}_{s= W_k(1)} \frac{e^{s t}}{s-e^{-s}} .$$
As the poles are simple, we have that
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{1}{s-e^{-s}} \right\} = \sum_k \frac{\exp\left[ W_k(1) t \right]}{1+ W_k(1)} $$